# Javascript - in a loop, adding 1 week to date object misbehaves after 6 months of being correct

Tags: javascript, date, object, increment

This Javascript generates a speaker list for each Sunday for a year.
It begins on 3-May-2015 and is correct through 1-Nov-2015.
When a week is added to 1-Nov-2015, it generates 7-Nov-2015 
instead of 8-Nov-2015 (in Firefox, IE, and Opera).  What have I done wrong?
The output looks like this:
...
25-Oct-2015 Delta (OK)
 1-Nov-2015 Alpha (OK)
 7-Nov-2015 Bravo (the error -- see output)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Speaker List Generator</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script>
'use strict';
// Handy faux constants
var MINUTE = 60 * 1000;
var HOUR =   MINUTE * 60;
var DAY =    HOUR   * 24;
var WEEK =   DAY    *  7;

var month_str = new Array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');

var speakers = new Array();
speakers[0]  = new Array();
speakers = [['Alpha','#FFFAAE'],['Bravo','#FFE3CD'],['Charlie','#AEFFB3'],['Delta','#D2FFFF'],['Echo','#EDEDED']];

// Initialize first date to May 3rd, 2015
var date_obj = new Date('May 3, 2015');
var d = date_obj.getDate();
var m = month_str[date_obj.getMonth()];
var y = date_obj.getFullYear();
var day = '';
</script>
</head>

<body style='font-family:courier'>

<h3>Speaker List</h3>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Date</th><th>Speaker</th>
</tr>
<script>
// For each month
for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
  // For each speaker
  for (var i = 0; i < speakers.length; i++) {
    // Echo only speaks on a 5th Sunday.
    // If Echo comes up, check for 1st Sunday.
    if ((speakers[i][0] == 'Echo') && (d < 8)) {
      continue;
    }
    // Add a space to 1 digit days
    day = (d < 10)?'&nbsp;'+d:d;
    document.writeln();
    document.writeln("  <tr>");
    document.writeln("    <td>"+day+"-"+m+"-"+y+"</td><td>"+speakers[i][0]+"</td>");
    document.writeln("  </tr>");

    // Add a week to the date for the next round.
    date_obj.setTime(date_obj.getTime() + WEEK);

    // Get next d, m, and y
    d = date_obj.getDate();
    m = month_str[date_obj.getMonth()];
    y = date_obj.getFullYear();
  }
}
</script>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the described behavior - Instead of 1-Nov-2015, '31-Oct-2015' is generated.

Comment: @collapsar: The DST dates are different in your locale than in the OP's.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just noticed that the previous date is '25-Oct-2015'. Smart analysis!

Answer (score 5):

The way you're adding a week will fail when crossing daylight saving time boundaries, because you're adding exactly 24 hours, but some days have 23 hours and some have 25.

You can avoid that by setting the *day* instead. Change

```
date_obj.setTime(date_obj.getTime() + WEEK);
```

to

```
date_obj.setDate(date_obj.getDate() + 7);
```

Don't worry about wrapping to the next month, the `Date` object will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the Daylight Saving Time ends on November 1st 2015 (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=2015).

It's probably better to use a library like moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) to take care of that for you.

```
var date = moment('20151101', 'YYYYMMDD')

date.calendar()
"11/01/2015"

date.add(7, 'days')

date.calendar()
"11/08/2015"
```